# Why is this code not causing my computer's memory to run out?

Tags: java, windows-7, garbage-collection

While playing around with something, I came across something like this. This piece of code is not causing my memory to run out.

```
while(true)
{
    Person p=new Person();       
}
```

Unless garbage collection is running every few seconds, I can't tell why my memory usage (in task manager) is not going up.

So does garbage collection in java run that often? Or does the task manager in windows not do a good job in showing the memory usage?

**Update**:
I monitored it with Java Visual VM. The garbage collector was never activated in the a few minutes I ran it.

Comment: The GC is good at doing its job I guess?

Comment: If you really want to run out of memory, make a List and push each person into it...

Comment: As you code doesn't do anything useful your `Person` object could be placed on the stack or discarded all together.  Why wouldn't you expect the GC to run if you run out of memory, to give you back some memory? i.e. that's it's job after all.

Comment: I monitored it with Java Visual VM. The garbage collector was never activated in the a few minutes I ran it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GC knows when to run, it runs when it needs to do so, the scope (life time) of `Person` is too short and the GC will sweep it while its in the Eden space and it will not be even promoted to older generations.

Comment: To see garbage collection runs, try to run the code using these command-line arguments: `-verbose:gc -Xmx16m`. This reduces available memory to 16 Mb, and prints GC runs. With a larger memory pool, the GC runs happen less frequently.

Comment: I tried java Main -verbose:gc -Xmx16m. It did not print any gc runs.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection in Java will essentially run as often as necessary. Whenever the heap gets filled up, GC will happen.  If you don't allocate, the GC won't run, if you do nothing but allocate, the GC will run quite often.  More to the point, Java will never OutOfMemoryError without trying to run the GC first.

The JIT can also, in some cases, recognize when an object clearly falls out of scope or is only needed locally, and can stack allocate in that case, not requiring any GC at all.

Comment: by heap you mean space? because minor GC occur before the heap become  full

Comment: I assume that at least some generation in the heap became full to trigger the GC, even if its the small Eden generation.

Answer (score 0):

in e each loop you create the object and destroy it. The garbage only free memory when it is necessary. if you want make a memory error only you must create an ArrayList out of the while and in the while add person to the ArrayList.